# Closed: How to read a temporary file as bytes in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

So basically I am using `flutter_sound` to record an audio file:

```
class AudioRecorder {
  FlutterSoundRecorder? _audioRecorder;
  String tempFilePath = "audio_recording.mp4";

  Future<void> init() async {
    _audioRecorder = FlutterSoundRecorder();
    await _audioRecorder!.openRecorder();
  }

  Future<void> dispose() async {
    await _audioRecorder!.openRecorder();
    _audioRecorder = null;
  }

  Future<void> startRecording() async {
    await _audioRecorder!.startRecorder(toFile: tempFilePath);
  }

  Future<File> stopRecording() async {
    await _audioRecorder!.stopRecorder();
    return File(tempFilePath);
  }
}
```

This class works as intended and a file is returned by `stopRecording();`.

**The issue:**

When I try to `audioFile.readAsBytesSync();`, this error occurs:

> Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = 'audio_recording.mp4' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)

**What I think is wrong:**

When I do `print(audioFile.path);`, the output is `"audio_recording.mp4"` however when I stop recording the audio, `flutter_sound` also prints a path to the file but its different:

> "/Users/.../Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/.../data/Containers/Data/Application/.../tmp/audio_recording.mp4"

When I `readAsBytesSync` to a `File` object that has this path, there is no exception. So I somehow have to get this path but I cannot figure out how. I have tried using `path_provider and getTemporaryDirectory` but its to no avail since the path from getTemporaryDirectory is different to the one printed by flutter_sound.

How could I fix this?

Thank you!

Comment: I have no experience with `package:flutter_sound`, but glancing at the documentation, have you tried calling `startRecorder` with an absolute path?  Or perhaps checking the `String` returned by `stopRecorder`?

Comment: @jamesdlin tell me why I never realized that ``stopRecorder();`` returns a fricking string :(