# Flutter: Is the sound really recorded in the designated file?

Tags: flutter, dart, audio, audio-recording, audiorecord

Recently I am using a package named `flutter_sound v9.1.7`. Here are some of the codes.

```
String _mPath = 'tau_file.mp4';
Codec _codec = Codec.aacMP4;
File? file;
FlutterSoundPlayer? _mPlayer = FlutterSoundPlayer();
FlutterSoundRecorder? _mRecorder = FlutterSoundRecorder();
void record() async {
    _mRecorder!
        .startRecorder(
      toFile: _mPath,
      codec: _codec,
      audioSource: AudioSource.microphone,
    )
        .then((value) {});

    setState(() {
      recording = true;
    });
  }
```

I have succeeded in recording and playing audio, but when I finish recording and try to analyze the seeming audio file `tau_file.mp4`, such like get the length of the file, an error occurred:
`Cannot retrieve length of file, path = 'tau_file.mp4' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)`.
The analysis code is here:

```
file = File(_mPath);
print(file?.path);
print(file?.absolute);
print(file?.length.toString());
```

I tried to seek answer in source codes, but only found an interface... So is the audio really be written to the file `tau_file.mp4`? Or maybe the process of analysis is wrong?

This is the first time that I use flutter_sound. Thanks for your help.

Comment: 1. [The `startRecorder` documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_sound/latest/recorder/FlutterSoundRecorder/startRecorder.html) documentation states that `toFile` is "a path to the file being recorded or the name of a temporary file (without slash '/')." Since you have not supplied a full path, it will be the name of a temporary file. 2. Your `record` function does not return a `Future`, and there is no way for callers to determine when the recording is complete.  If you attempt to access the file prematurely, it might not exist yet.

Comment: 1. So I need to provide an absolute path in my phone for the file, then it can be a really existed file? 2. Actually there is another function named `stop` to stoping recording.

Comment: 1. I have no experience with the flutter_sound package, but based solely on the documentation, you'd either need an absolute path or a relative one (e.g. `'./file'`) to write to the file directly instead of to a temporary one. 2. The point remains that you need to wait for the `Future`s to complete before you can expect the file to be usable.  Also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/70934354/

Answer (score 0):

```
void stopRecorder() async {
    await _mRecorder!.stopRecorder().then((value) {
      setState(() {
        //var url = value;
        recordedUrl = value;
        debugPrint('path : -------- $recordedUrl');
        _mplaybackReady = true;
      });
    });
  }
```

This is your recorded files url, when you stop the record you can get it.
The document includes this code. It gives you `//var url = value;`. Then you can handle it. like `var recordedFile = File(url);`. it's not a temporary one. You can upload it somewhere or whatever you like.